# Android Difficulty in placing points after focused canvas.scale operation

Tags: android, view, bitmap, scaling, gesture

This is my first ever question on stackoverflow so please go easy on me.

Let me give you little bit of background:

I have created an application that manipulates a bitmap within a view(the image in this case being a map of a facility) and I place points on the map using the actual x and y coordinates of the point on the bitmap. I track the offset of the top left corner of the bitmap relative to the top left corner of the screen by modifying this offset value based on the changes in the image placement made by gestures. This is actually working very well for panning and this allows me to easily convert a screen coordinate (from a long press gesture) into the actual coordinate on the bitmap. With this I draw a circle on the map and allow the user to create a "point of interest" that I push out to a database.

The problem arises when dealing with zoom. I am zooming with a simple
    `canvas.scale(scalefastor ,scalefactor);` 
in the onDraw. With this zoom, the actaul scaling is relative to the top left corner of the image so the pinch to zoom is not intuitive since the actual location you are trying to zoom into runs offscreen very quickly. The scaling of the image in this manner however does not effect the actual offset of the image though so my point placement is still accurate. I use the following simple math to accomplish this:

```
bitmapXCoordinate = (event.getX() - xOffset) /scaleFactor;
```

I would like to use

```
canvas.scale(scalefactor, scalefactor, gestureFocusX, gestureFocusY);
```

in order to keep the zoom intuitive to users but this does a transform on the actual matrix of the bitmap so that my point placement is is no longer functional. It seems that the point on the bitmap is now somehow relative to the focal point of the scale and all the placed points are off and tend toward this focal point.
I am aware that I need to take into account this transformation on the matrix in order to get my points placed correctly, but apparently, it takes a more intelligent individual than I. The solution is likely simple but I have been working on this for days trying to account for this new offset and I just can't get any real progress. Any insight into a solution for this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Still working on this with no solution in sight.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this for over a week, trying out various solutions before I found something that, while I don't understand it fully ;), has the benefit of working. You'll need a working implementation of a pinch-zoom (or whatever) imageview from which you can derive the current scale and translation values.

I think the difficulty with this problem stems from the fact that there are two problems to be solved: 1, decoding a click on a potentially scaled and translated image, and 2, rendering stored click positions.

Anyway, to the code. To register a touch:

```
private Float[] getNormalizedTouchLocation(MotionEvent event) {
    float xpos = getOffsetX();
    float ypos = getOffsetY();
    float scale = getScaleFactor();

    Drawable drawable = getDrawable();
    Rect image_bounds = drawable.getBounds();

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix(getImageMatrix());

    matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mPivotX, mPivotY);
    matrix.postTranslate(xpos, ypos);

    RectF image_rect = new RectF(image_bounds);

    matrix.mapRect(image_rect);

    float x = ((event.getX() - image_rect.left) / scale);
    float y = ((event.getY() - image_rect.top) / scale);

    return new Float[]{x, y};
}
```

Then to render:

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // Ensure parent leaves the canvas *unscaled* and *untranslated*.
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    float xpos = getOffsetX();
    float ypos = getOffsetY();
    float scale = getScaleFactor();

    canvas.save();

    Matrix matrix = canvas.getMatrix();
    matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mPivotX, mPivotY);
    matrix.postTranslate(xpos, ypos);

    Drawable drawable = getDrawable();
    Rect image_bounds = drawable.getBounds();

    RectF image_rect = new RectF(image_bounds);

    Matrix image_matrix = new Matrix(getImageMatrix());
    image_matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mPivotX, mPivotY);
    image_matrix.postTranslate(xpos, ypos);

    image_matrix.mapRect(image_rect);

    // mPoints is a list of float[2] coordinates.
    for (Float[] coord: mPoints) {

        // Draw a bitmap centered on each touch position.
        float x = (scale * coord[0] + image_rect.left) - mBitmap.getWidth() / 2;
        float y = (scale * coord[1] + image_rect.top) - mBitmap.getHeight() / 2;

        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, x, y, mPaint);
    }

    canvas.restore();
}
```

Hope this works for you! Obviously the solution here only renders correctly points that were registered on the same rendered-size image at the same screen resolution etc - it could probably be amended to store fractions of image width/ height for a solution that works across images/ resolutions.